# attribute value in directive angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i have html markup that i need to use at many places so rather to copy paste it again and again  but with different Headings

i thought to create a directive it looks like this

```
myModule.directive('row', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="row">'+
        '<div class="col-md-10 margin-top-10px font-18px">{{heading}}</div>'+
       ' <div class="col-md-2">'+
            '<div class="margin-top-10px"><span ng-click="close()" class="close helvetica color-black">&times;</span></div>'+
        '</div>'+
    '</div>',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            var test = attrs.heading;
        }

    };
```

});

and how i m trying to use it

```
 <row heading="its my heading "></row>
```

i cant make it work .i dont want to create isolated scope or child scope i just wanted to pass value from attribute and when template gets replaced i want its interpolated value .

can some one help me how can id o this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    scope.heading = attrs.heading;
}
```

It might also be a good idea to set

```
scope: true
```

You have to actually attach the value from the `attr` object to the scope before it can be used in the template.

Comment: thanku for helping me out . can i use bindonce because once the heading created it never change

Comment: I don't have much experience with bindonce, but I think it wouldn't make much sense because the approach for passing the value through the attribute doesn't create a watch.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
scope: {
  heading: '='
}
```

to your directive's definition to create 2 way data-binding with that attribute. you would do this if you are passing in a scope variable.

or use `@`

```
scope: {
  heading: '@'
}
```

if you are just passing in a string.

minimalist plunkr to demonstrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/U5OzlMiXaIsHEdb5gmRT